# Is it possible to do a count on a column using different formula for different conditions?

Tags: sql

So I have a table that consists of Category and its subtype, and the count method for each category/subtype combination is a little bit different.

When the subtype = 1, the count is the number of rows divided by 2
When the subtype = 2, the count is the number of rows

***Sample data:***
[image]

So for the table above I want to make a query to display the count for:

The total count of Category A subtype 1 and subtype 2
The total count of Category B subtype 1 and subtype 2
The total count of Category A subtype 1 only
The total count of Category B subtype 1 only

Which will look something like this:

***Sample query output:***
[image]

I'm having problem on how to get the count for the total on subtype 1 and subtype 2 together, as one type is using exact count of row and the other is using count of row then divided by 2.  Thought of using the Case but can't think of how to add them up together.  Appreciate if someone can give some hints

I'm having problem on how to get the count for the total on subtype 1 and subtype 2 together, as one type is using exact count of row and the other is using count of row then divided by 2.  Thought of using the Case but can't think of how to add them up together.  Appreciate if someone can give some hints

Comment: For category A `=(COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"A",B2:B9,1)/2)+COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"A",B2:B9,2)`.

Comment: @Harun24hr how is it going to look like when converting to SQL?

Comment: Excel doesn't support `SQL` language. If you need `SQL` then please tag proper database like `MSSQL`, `Oracle`, `MySQL` or so on....

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily once you know the trick.

First, you must understand that `count(x)` is equivalent to `sum(case when x is not null then 1 else 0 end)`.

Once you understand that, you then will quickly see that we can put whatever we like in the `case` statement.

We simply write a `case` statement that returns `1` for those we wish to count, and `0` for those we do not wish to count, and `sum` them.

```sql
Select
  sum(
    case 
    when t.Category = 'A' and t.SubType = 1 then 1
    when t.Category = 'A' and t.SubType = 2 then 1
    else 0 
    end
  ) as "Category A (1 + 2 count)",
  sum(
    case
    when t.Category = 'B' and t.SubType = 1 then 1
    when t.Category = 'B' and t.SubType = 2 then 1
    else 0 
    end
  ) as "Category B (1 + 2 count)"

from TableName t
```

I will leave the other columns to you.